# Javascript: removing object from array stored in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I have an array stored in localStorage that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "location": "westcliff, uk",
    "stopover": true
  },
  {
    "location": "westcliff, uk",
    "stopover": true
  },
  {
    "location": "southend, uk",
    "stopover": true
  },
  {
    "location": "Leigh-on-sea, uk",
    "stopover": true
  }
]
```

I have a button that when i click on, it will look for the `localtion:` in that array and it will delete that object from the array and then stores in the localstorage again.

The button code looks like this:

```
$(document).on('click', ".cart-del", function() {   
    var retrievedObject2 = localStorage.getItem('waypoints');
    var parsedObject2 = JSON.parse(retrievedObject2);
    var result2 = parsedObject2.filter(function(x){return x.location !== "westcliff, uk"; });
    var setLoc2 = JSON.stringify(result2);
    localStorage.setItem('waypoints', setLoc2);
}):
```

This all works fine.

The issue that i have is that when the button is clicked, it will remove every "`westcliff, uk`" object.

**What i need to do is to only remove 1 object per click!**

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I tried this and this doesn't remove anything from the array:

```
    $(document).on('click', ".cart-del", function() { 

    var retrievedObject2 = localStorage.getItem('waypoints');
    var parsedObject2 = JSON.parse(retrievedObject2);

    for(var i = 0; i < parsedObject2.length; i++){
    if(parsedObject2[i].text == "westcliff, uk"){
    parsedObject2.splice(i, 1);
    break;
    }
    }



    var result2 = parsedObject2;    

    var setLoc2 = JSON.stringify(result2);
    localStorage.setItem('waypoints', setLoc2);
    }):
```

Comment: Don't use `.filter`. Write a loop that removes the first matching element it finds and then breaks out of the loop.

Comment: Storing the array in localStorage is totally irrelevant to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using `filter`, there's no way to exit early so it may not be an appropriate tool for this use case. Instead you can just use a regular loop. Here's an example.

```js
var a = [
  {text : "foo", n : 1 },
  {text : "foo", n : 2 }
];
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
  if(a[i].text == "foo"){
    a.splice(i, 1);
    break;
  }
}
console.log(a);
```

Or a neater approach using [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex?v=example) :

```js
var a = [
  {text : "foo", n : 1 },
  {text : "foo", n : 2 }
];

a.findIndex((obj, i) => {
  if(obj.text === "foo"){
    a.splice(i,1);
    return true;
  }
});

console.log(a);
```

Comment: You are using a.splice(i,1); which only removes {text : "foo", n : 1 }.. so it will not work for {text : "foo", n : 2 } or {text : "foo", n : 3 } ?

Comment: Isn't that what you said you wanted? To only remove the first element that matches the condition?

Comment: Nope. I said, What i need to do is to only remove 1 object per click! Example: click once and remove 1, click again and remove another etc etc...

Comment: Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: If you look at my own Array, i don't even have the n : 1 in my array. YOu just put it in your example.

Comment: Ok, but this code will do that. Each time it's run it will remove the first matching element. If you call it multiple times(i.e on multiple clicks) it will remove the first one each time from what's left. As for the `n` thing, it was just to demonstrate which element got removed.

Comment: right. i tried your code based on my own code and it didn't work. I will update my question.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Although, you should always clarify what you mean by "didn't work" :)

Comment: I just edited my question with the new code based on your example. and by it didn't work i mean it just didn't remove anything from the array.

Comment: Because you used `.text` from my example object, not `.location` from your own data.

Comment: Hmm. Well, maybe it's a timing issue with `localStorage`? Remember that if you click very quickly then you might get old versions of `waypoints` coming from `localStorage` before the modified versions can be saved. It's hard to say without seeing your full code. But the code I presented definitely works for multiple iterations in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use find method instead of filter method

```
parsedObject2.find(function(x,e){
   if(x.location == "westcliff, uk")
     {
       return x.splice(e,1)
     }
 });
```

Comment: I think that code will do the same thing as OP's code, it will remove all instances. Look at [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=example#Description) for find, if you don't return true it will execute for all elements in the array.

Comment: Yeah, that works because you `return`ed the truthy return value of `splice` in the fiddle. But in the code in your answer here you don't `return`.